# How to install Network Manager offline

Tags: linux, networking, rpm, suse

So I was trying to install Network Manager for my SLES 15 SP4
and I finally fixed all the dependencies issue.

However, the last dependency made me extremely confuse.
The NetwrokManager needs NetworkManager-branding, but the NetworkManager-branding also needs NetworkManager!!
How could it happend?

I can't connect to my network through setup with YaST, although "ip address" shows eth3 is UP, it can't get the IP from DHCP. (it's the reason why I wanna try NetworkManager)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A) I think it would work to list both RPMs in one RPM install command

B) You can do `rpm --install --nodeps ...` to install a package with missing dependencies.  Just install one of the two packages using `--nodeps`, and then you can install the other normally.